# Why is the type of ref not recognized in the child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, scrollview, use-ref

I'm passing a component in a ScrollView and there I pass the ref too.

```js
const GameMulti: FC<GameMultiProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView & scrollViewProps>(null);
// Should be:
// const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView & React.RefObject<ScrollView>>(null);
...

 <ScrollView
          ref={scrollViewRef}

>

  <DetailedAnswer
    scrollViewRef={scrollViewRef}
  />

...
```

**DetailedAnswer.tsx**

```js
export type scrollViewProps = {
  current: {
    scrollTo: ({ y, animated, }: { y: number, animated: boolean }) => { y: number, animated: boolean }
  }
};

interface Props {
  scrollViewRef: ScrollView & scrollViewProps
// Should be:
// scrollViewRef: React.RefObject<ScrollView>
}

const DetailedAnswer: FC<Props> = ({ scrollViewRef }) => {

  if (scrollViewRef.current) // not needed
    scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true });
```

I've created the `scrollViewProps` because the one from `react-native` was giving me an error with `current`.

But now I get an error in the above:

```js
 <DetailedAnswer
    scrollViewRef={scrollViewRef}
  />
```

```js
Type 'RefObject<ScrollView & scrollViewProps>' is not assignable to type 'ScrollView & scrollViewProps'.
  Type 'RefObject<ScrollView & scrollViewProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'ScrollView': scrollTo, scrollToEnd, flashScrollIndicators, getScrollResponder, and 38 more.ts(2322)
DetailedAnswer.tsx(33, 3): The expected type comes from property 'scrollViewRef' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

Comment: Quick answer - this `scrollViewRef` does not return the same type as `scrollViewProps` - `scrollViewProps` is not a RefObject, so it is missing a lot of properties. Does this help? Got other questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jnelson stated (kinda), the type of `scrollViewRef` should be a RefObject.

```js
interface Props {
  scrollViewRef: React.RefObject<ScrollView>;
}
```

You don't need to create a separate type as scrollViewProps.

Also, FYI, you don't need to check if scrollViewRef.current is truthy if you're going to use optional chaining. You can remove `if (scrollViewRef.current)`. `scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo` will suffice.

Comment: Hi @Ugur, thanks for the solution. Now everything is working.

Comment: @FotiosTsakiris my pleasure, but you edited your post and included `const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView & React.RefObject<ScrollView>>(null);`. useRef adds the RefObject type, you don't need to pass it. In fact, this will break your code. It should be `const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);`. We use RefObject because useRef hook returns `RefObject<T>`, instead of the type we passed. So with your edit, return type is now `RefObject<RefObject<ScrollView>>` instead of `RefObject<ScrollView>`. This is not the type you would want.

Comment: Right! But, without the ScrollView, I was getting 2 errors. One from the ref in the ScrollView: `Type 'RefObject<RefObject<ScrollView>>' is not assignable to type 'string | RefObject<ScrollView> | ((instance: ScrollView | null) => void) | null | undefined'.` And one for the child component where I pass the ref: `Type 'RefObject<RefObject<ScrollView>>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<ScrollView>'.`